# javax.naming.namingexception cannot create resource instance tomcat 7

Tags: tomcat

I know these qq has been posted many times over this forum but still am getting this error message. here is my configuration stuff

context.xml:

```
<Context>    
<ResourceLink global="jdbc/cpWebDatasource" name="jdbc/cpWebDatasource" type="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource"/>
</Context>
```

//cpWebDatasource is the datasource name

Server.xml:

```
<GlobalNamingResources>
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
    <Resource name="jdbc/cpWebDatasource" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              username="qa_cp_dml" password="qa_cp_dml"
              url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.210.145.26:1521/QATESTNEW"
              driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
              initialSize="5" maxWait="5000"
              maxActive="120" maxIdle="5"
              validationQuery="select 1"
              poolPreparedStatements="true"/>

  </GlobalNamingResources>
```

Web.xml:

```
<resource-ref>
   <description>Db</description>
   <res-ref-name>cpWebDatasource</res-ref-name>
   <res-type>oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource</res-type>
   <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

Actually my application is running in JBoss4.x we are migrating it to tomact7 .to be part of it required to do the datasource configuration stuff.

Any help will be greatly appreciated ...
Thanks in advance

Comment: can you show the stacktrace ?

Answer (score 0):

The `< res-ref-name >` in the web.xml should be: `jdbc/cpWebDatasource`